# I have built my Nuxt app through Cloud Build, how do I now deploy it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a [simple Nuxt app](https://github.com/chrissyast/devprofile),

added a cloudbuild.yaml...

```
steps:
- name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']
```

The build ran successfully but I have no idea where the files created from the build went, and how I now deploy this build. Locally I would just run `npm run start` but when I tried adding that to my cloudbuild the build logs just showed `listening on localhost:3000`. In any case, I have a feeling I shouldn't be adding the `start` command to my build.

I am very new to CI/CD. I have previously deployed this code on Heroku with minimal difficulty but now I'm trying to run it on GCP and struggling.

I have seen examples of running the build locally and then pushing the whole thing to GCP but I'd like to be able to do it all automatically just from a push to master.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) and an `AppYAML` file (can have any name so long as the extension is `.yaml`), you simply have to go to the directory `YourAppYaml.yaml` is in and run [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy):

```
gcloud app deploy YourAppYaml.yaml
```

---

(If you would prefer to not have to type `YourAppYaml.yaml`/`--appyaml=YourAppYaml.yaml` every time you run `gcloud app deploy`, you can simply rename `YourAppYaml.yaml` to `app.yaml`)

---

Given that you've specified wanting to "be able to do it all automatically just from a push to master", I believe what you're looking for is [this](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories), however doing it through Cloud build does require that you include the following step (otherwise you're just building without deploying, which would defeat the purpose):

#### `cloudbuild.yaml` (aka `Cloud Build build config file`):

```yaml
- name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'install']
- name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

#### If you want to deploy it manually without using a trigger:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

You can find more detailed instructions on how to perform Google Cloud Build builds from CLI using either `Dockerfile`s or `YAML`s [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/running-builds/start-build-command-line-api#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Build%20build%20config%20file) (the `.yaml` and `Dockerfile` examples are in the same `gcloud` tab, I've linked text to direct you to the `.yaml` version within said tab)

---

Alternatively there is [Github Actions] (https://github.com/features/actions), more specifically [this google action that deploys to app engine](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine) (I would recommend reading the description thoroughly, as some Google documentation can have important information that is easy to overlook)

Comment: I added the `gcr.io...` step, which got me closer to where I wanted to be, then I had to add an app.yaml, then got over various permissions errors until finally I got:

`"ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a cloudbuild.yaml in the current directory, and the runtime field in /workspace/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: nodejs]. To use your cloudbuild.yaml to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [nodejs] runtime, please remove the cloudbuild.yaml from this directory."`
But then if I remove cloudbuild.yaml the build can't run...

Comment: Sorry, my answer was rather limited to just deployment, I should've been a bit more detailed and included [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-nodejs#configuring_nodejs_builds) which explains that you can use `npm` as a step to run the build/installation - Cloud Build is based around Docker, so having `npm` as the first step will tell CB to start with `FROM node` when building. I've noticed that you've transitioned from cloudbuild.yaml to Dockerfile, I can guide you through using Dockerfile instead of CB if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, no in the end I got so frustrated with trying to do it through cloudbuild that I just changed to a Dockerfile and was able to achieve what I wanted within minutes!

Comment: That's great, I apologize for my poor wording, I'm editing the answer as I write this to make it easier for anyone coming in to try and figure this out as well.

Comment: No need to apologise! I think it's just GCP is far too confusing on this. I wanted to replicate what I would do locally, i.e. do `build` which generates the files and then `start` which actually serves them, which seemed simple enough, but I didn't understand where the generated files were going and how to trigger the `start` part once that was done. Thankfully doing it via a Dockerfile handles that all in one go

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't blame GCP this time around, I mixed up the `app deploy` and `builds submit` commands, I've corrected it now.